# What are the projectile speeds of Ana's unscoped Biotic Rifle and Sleep Dart?

Tags: overwatch

I know that Ana's scoped shots with her Biotic Rifle are hitscan, but what is the projectile speed of her unscoped shot? And the speed of her Sleep Dart?

I was able to find the projectile speeds for other projectile heroes like [Zenyatta](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zenyatta) and [Hanzo](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Hanzo), but finding them for Ana is difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Ana), the projectile speed of her Biotic Rifle is 85.5 m/s. I don't know why I didn't think to check the Overwatch Wikia until after I posted this question.

I still don't know about the speed of her Sleep Dart though.

**Edit:** I did some *non-scientific* testing of her sleep dart. I went to the practice range and fired three times at a test bot at a range of 40 meters. The video I recorded can be found [here](https://youtu.be/S_-oFr4mLDg), and the screenshots of the start and end times are below. I've chosen the start timestamp when I see the flash of light from the gun and the end timestamp when I see the hit mark on the crosshair. In the screenshots, the timestamp is in the bottom left hand corner.

1. [23.784s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1cjy.jpg) to [24.550s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddC2A.jpg) (delta = 0.766s)
2. [37.800s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2MVe.jpg) to [38.567s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXh89.jpg) (delta = 0.767s)
3. [51.634s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LZII.jpg) to [52.400s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmUNV.jpg) (delta = 0.766s)

So if we do math:

- 40m / 0.766s = 52.22 m/s
- 40m / 0.767s = 52.15 m/s

So Ana's sleep dart projectile speed is around **52.2 m/s**. Totally not a rigorous scientific test, but it's something.

Comment: This is purely from self observation, but her sleep dart seems to have the same speed as her unscoped biotic rifle

Comment: For comparison, I recently found this [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Competitiveoverwatch/comments/57wjjf/what_is_anas_projectile_hipfire_and_sleep_dart/d8vni6q/) that suggests (from self observation probably) that the sleep dart is slower than her unscoped rifle shot.

Comment: @dustyjuicebox, purely from self observation sleep dart is slower. Also I did a test firing sleep dart and a rifle shot at a bot at the same position, I hit with the shot, but missed by far with sleep dart.

Comment: Just so the math is here. Assuming the original video is 60fps as well, it will have at least 1 fps error for start and end time of the animation. I.e. 2/60 = 0.033 sec. Making the speed to be in the range from 40/0.799 = 50 m/s to 40/0.733 = 54.6 m/s.
The error can be easily twice bigger, since we don't know how to detect the start and the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I did some test too, comparing Sleep Dart and Biotic Rifle Shot. Here is the video:

I believe it could be more illustrative, since I've used moving target you can see that you must fire sleep dart much more far away from the target if you want to hit it.

I used practice range, being at second floor and firing at the most far away moving bot.

Sleep Dart:
46 frames from the moment of animation start (yellow ability icon) 
to hit (red half circle at the bot)
28 frames from the moment of firing (bullet out of the gun) to hit

Rifle Shot:
14 frames from the moment of animation start = firing to hit

If shot speed is 85.5 m/s
Then sleep dart speed ≈ 85.5*14/28 = 42.8 m/s ± 9 m/s (taking into account 1-2 frame error)

If we taking into account sleep shot animation (46-28=18 frames) 
and human reaction time (0.25s =15 frames), then we need to react ≈1.5 times earlier 
with sleep dart than with rifle shot (at the given distance used for testing).